# JavaScript JSON API Parser w/ Default Values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, frontend, web-frontend

When consuming an external JSON API I expect certain values but I need to guard against bad inputs since I cannot control the external API.

Writing a local parser class is an option but seems pretty tedious. I need to check that the properties exist and that they are the right type (e.g. that the API did not return a string instead of an array or object) and this quickly adds up to a decent chunk of code.

Are there any standard ways of dealing with this? Any popular libraries? I tried a Google search but could not find anything.

Comment: JsonSchema https://json-schema.org/? And exemplary JS validator https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Answer (score 3):

[RunScope](https://www.runscope.com/) (www.runscope.com) and [Assertible](https://assertible.com/) (www.assertible.com) seem like a good commercial alternative to do what you are looking for, i.e. validate or guard against bad inputs from your API Call result at a Test Level.

From a Programmatic point of view, however, you could use a Library called 'REST-Assured' to do the JSON Schema validation against API Call Output.

The following article elaborates with a detailed coding example for performing JSON Schema Validation against JSON/REST API call

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-json-schema